# iPad auto locks even with auto lock ‘never’

Tags: ios, settings, screen-lock

My iPad Air 2 auto locks suddenly without any sign as to why, and the lock screen comes up. I have checked the settings and the auto lock is set to ‘never’ yet it auto locks. What could be the problem and what can be the possible solutions?

Comment: idk that model... does it have Touch ID? If so, then it will always auto-lock as soon as the screen switches off. (If not...idk ;)

Comment: Does it happen randomly or after a specific idle time?

Comment: It happens in around like 1 min 20 sec to 1 min 40 sec but it may sometimes even happen in 20 sec. I have no idea what is happening

Comment: It does have a touch ID but have not set that :)